# How to add jFreeChart library with the netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, servlets, jfreechart, netbeans-6.9

I am having jCommon(jFreeChart) library file. (It contains ant, checkstyle, docfiles, experimental, lib, source, swt, tests, ChangeLog, jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jar, licence-LGPL.txt, maven-jfreechart-project.xml, NEWS,Readme.txt) I've used NetbeansIDE6.9 to add into the netbeans new library there are three tabs classpath,source,javadoc. javadoc tab need index-all.html file. How to add this and run the application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Project properties -> Libraries -> Add JAR/Folder -> Browser JAR`

To add source, you need to have source downloaded. As I can see in your given list, you are having one. You can select JAR you just added, using a method I have stated above, and click `Edit`. There you will have another pop-up with the `tab` "Sources". You can add source JAR in there.

To add Javadocs, you need to download it first. Then just add that `zip` file, most probably by following similar steps.

**P.S.:** *Learn Maven, you will love it. It will manage all these things for you automagically. You just need to provide the artifacts.*

Comment: @user524780: There must be some `jar` file in the `lib` directory you mentioned. :)